# How can I ensure that the "details" task pane in microsoft project vba is NOT displayed

Tags: vba, ms-project, customtaskpane

I have an application in Microsoft project that performs a Backtrace of a task and then uses the following to save that image to an Excel Tab

Application.EditCopyPicture Object:=False, ForPrinter:=0, SelectedRows:=0, FromDate:=EarliestStart, ToDate:=LFin, ScaleOption:=pjCopyPictureShowOptions, MaxImageHeight:=-1#, MaxImageWidth:=-1#, MeasurementUnits:=2

definitions for msome of the variables used in the procedure:
EarliestStart = StatusDate-30
Lfin = Finish of the target Task for the Backtrace, which would be the last task in the string.

I use a flag field to identify tasks that I want to create a backtrace for and then cycle through all the tasks to create the Backtrace images and saving them to a unique excel tab.

Every so often, my app "creates a secondary task pane" using the same view that I am using in the top half of the split screen.  I do not want a split screen with the bottom half of the screen displayed. When I have a split screen, my application

Is there a vba command that I can use in code that will test for the presence of a secondary task pane and if present, clear it.  I have been looking for something that would test the Ribbon task\details checkbox but have been unable to find it.

If before running the application I remove the secondary pane, it runs fine.  If I start to run the vba with a secondary pane showing, it brings up a View "View" dialog.

I have experimented with:

ViewApplyEx SinglePane:=True, ApplyTo:=1
but this displays the View"Views" dialog and forces me to select a view from the list, which is not what I want to do.

Any suggestions as to where I should look?

Answer (score 0):

The method you are looking for is [PaneClose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.paneclose). It will close the lower pane of the active window. It does nothing if the lower pane was already closed. So do this:

```
Application.PaneClose
Application.EditCopyPicture Object:=False, ForPrinter:=0, SelectedRows:=0, FromDate:=EarliestStart, ToDate:=LFin, ScaleOption:=pjCopyPictureShowOptions, MaxImageHeight:=-1#, MaxImageWidth:=-1#, MeasurementUnits:=2
```